# how to add a description to the tavern.yaml?

Tags: pytest

I work with Tavern in VSCode.
Integrated Allure with Pytest.
I want to add a "description" to the yaml file, how to do it correctly so that it does not give the error "unexpected"?

my code

```js
test_name: "api_auth"

stages:
  - name: "Auth_ris_api"
    request:
      url: "http://192.168.22.22:10114/ris/auth/login"
      method: POST
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
      json:
        username: "admin"
        password: "123"
    response:
      status_code: 200
      save:
        token: json.body.token
```

ChatGPT says that you can simply insert a description: into the code and write a text, but this method does not work, I did not find an answer on the forums, help if you can)

Error:

```
E           tavern._core.exceptions.BadSchemaError: 
E           ---
E
E           Additional properties are not allowed ('description' was unexpected)
E           D:\python\tavern\test002.tavern.yaml: line 8-28:
E
E           stages:
E             - name: "Auth_ris_api"
E               description: "Шаг авторизации"
E               request:
E                 url: "http://192.168.22.22:10114/ris/auth/login"
E                 method: POST
E                 headers:
E                   Content-Type: application/json
E                 json:
E                   username: "admin"
E                   password: "123"
E               response:
E                 status_code: 200
E                 save:
E                   token: json.body.token
```

Comment: Be more explicit: "but this method does not work..." does not provide any info